# Create checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a problem, when I create checkbox using javascript, the checkbox cannot be checked or unchecked. My code in javascript is:

```js
function createNewCheckboxt(name, id){
  var box = document.createElement("li");
  box.innerHTML = '<div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary"><input type="checkbox" name="cbrand" id="'+id+'" value="'+name+'" checked=""><label for="data'+ id +'">'+ name +'</label>'; 
   document.getElementById("brand").appendChild(box);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list_brand_merchant" id="brand">
</ul>
```

Comment: I am able check and uncheck it. Could you please check console and confirm if there are any errors?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/356zyLwz/ <- fiddle link to support my comment above

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/4rybx9xj/

Comment: there might be something else , some javascript changing it back. Or maybe a transparent div overlaying it. As your code works fine

Comment: Don't create elements via huge blobs of HTML in a string. This is not 2006, and we are not programming in jQuery any more. Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: may be you have some top layer beyond that checkbox, just put inspect element and check it...becoz ur code is working fine...

Comment: it solve now, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer to correct misunderstanding of the question.

Your original code is below:

```
function createNewCheckboxt(name, id) {
    // Create a li as the container of the input and the label elements
    var box = document.createElement("li");

    // Write input and label HTML to the container
    box.innerHTML = '<div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" name="cbrand" id="' + id + '" value="' + name + '" checked="">' +
                        '<label for="data' + id + '">' + name + '</label>';

    // Get the ul element by ID then append the container to it
    document.getElementById("brand").appendChild(box);
}
```

From your code above, the only reason I guess is that you are trying to click on the `label` to check/uncheck the checkbox which doesn't work.

You give the `input` element an ID like this `id="' + id + '"` but the `label` element's `for` attribute is actually `for="data' + id + '"` which has an extra *data* string in it hence clicking on the `label` element won't trigger check/uncheck of the checkbox.

To fix it, either make the ID of the `input` as `id="data' + id + '"` or change to `label` to `for="' + id + '"`.

Comment: It doesn't seem his problem was creating the checkbox--he seems pretty clear that the problem is that for some reason it can't be checked or unchecked.